# In WebGL- How to have textures and colors at the same time by changing the shaderProgram

Tags: colors, webgl, shader, textures

I have another problem with WebGL -learning curve is steep, I apologize :(  - Anyway, so I am trying to have a program that shows a colored pyramid and a textured cube. I used the WebGL tutorial based on Nehe's OpenGL tutorial and basically tried to mesh tutorials 4 and 5 together to see how that would work if I just played with the shader Program stuff, but it didn't work for some reason... Any ideas? Also, I was wondering if anyone could let me know how long it takes to get a firm grasp on WebGL? I've gotten a lot of basic concepts down, but it seems like such a steep mountain to climb in terms of learning it thoroughly...

```
<html><head>
    <title>Learning WebGL Lesson 5</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>

    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
        }
        </script>

    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;


        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        }
        </script>




    <script id="shader-fcol" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 vColor;

        void main(void) {
            gl_FragColor = vColor;
        }
        </script>

    <script id="shader-vcol" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

        varying vec4 vColor;

        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
            vColor = aVertexColor;
        }
        </script>














    <script type="text/javascript">

        var gl;

        function initGL(canvas) {
            try {
                gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
                gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
                gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
            } catch (e) {
            }
            if (!gl) {
                alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
            }
        }


        function getShader(gl, id) {
            var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
            if (!shaderScript) {
                return null;
            }

            var str = "";
            var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
            while (k) {
                if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                    str += k.textContent;
                }
                k = k.nextSibling;
            }

            var shader;
            if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
            gl.compileShader(shader);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                return null;
            }

            return shader;
        }





        var shaderProgram;
        var shaderProgram2;

        function initShaders() {
            var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
            var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

            shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert("Could not initialise shaders");
            }

           // gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

            shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

            shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

            shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
            shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
            shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");






            ////////////

            var colorShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fcol");
            var vertcolorShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vcol");

            shaderProgram2 = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram2, vertcolorShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram2, colorShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram2);

            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram2, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert("Could not initialise shaders");
            }

            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram2);

            shaderProgram2.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram2, "aVertexPosition");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram2.vertexPositionAttribute);

            shaderProgram2.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram2, "aVertexColor");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram2.vertexColorAttribute);

            shaderProgram2.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uPMatrix");
            shaderProgram2.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "uMVMatrix");






        }


        function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
        }


        var neheTexture;

        function initTexture() {
            neheTexture = gl.createTexture();
            neheTexture.image = new Image();
            neheTexture.image.onload = function () {
                handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture)
            }

            neheTexture.image.src = "nehe.gif";
        }


        var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
        var mvMatrixStack = [];
        var pMatrix = mat4.create();

        function mvPushMatrix() {
            var copy = mat4.create();
            mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
            mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
        }

        function mvPopMatrix() {
            if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
                throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
            }
            mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
        }


        function setMatrixUniforms() {
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
        }


        function degToRad(degrees) {
            return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        var cubeVertexPositionBuffer;
        var cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer;
        var cubeVertexIndexBuffer;

        function initBuffers() {
            cubeVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
            vertices = [
                        // Front face
                        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

                        // Back face
                        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                        // Top face
                        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

                        // Bottom face
                        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                        // Right face
                        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                        1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                        // Left face
                        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
                        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
                        ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            cubeVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 24;

            cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
            var textureCoords = [
                                 // Front face
                                 0.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0,

                                 // Back face
                                 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 0.0,

                                 // Top face
                                 0.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0,

                                 // Bottom face
                                 1.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 0.0,

                                 // Right face
                                 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 0.0,

                                 // Left face
                                 0.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0,
                                 ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
            cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = 24;

            cubeVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
            var cubeVertexIndices = [
                                     0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
                                     4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
                                     8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
                                     12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
                                     16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
                                     20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
                                     ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            cubeVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
            cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = 36;







            ///////////////


            pyramidVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
            var vertices = [
                            // Front face
                            0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                            1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

                            // Right face
                            0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                            1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
                            1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                            // Back face
                            0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                            1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

                            // Left face
                            0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
                            ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 12;

            pyramidVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
            var colors = [
                          // Front face
                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

                          // Right face
                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

                          // Back face
                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

                          // Left face
                          1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                          0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
                          ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
            pyramidVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 12;



















        }


        var xRot = 0;
        var yRot = 0;
        var zRot = 0;

        function drawScene() {



            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram2);

            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-3.7, 0.0, -15.0]);

            mvPushMatrix();
            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(rPyramid), [0, 1, 0]);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram2.vertexPositionAttribute, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexColorBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram2.vertexColorAttribute, pyramidVertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            setMatrixUniforms();
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, pyramidVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);

            mvPopMatrix();





            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);



            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [2.7, 0.0, -15.0]);

            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(xRot), [1, 0, 0]);
            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(yRot), [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(zRot), [0, 0, 1]);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexPositionBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, cubeVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, neheTexture);
            gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexIndexBuffer);
            setMatrixUniforms();
            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, cubeVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);




                    }


        var lastTime = 0;

        function animate() {
            var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
            if (lastTime != 0) {
                var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

                xRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
                yRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
                zRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
            }
            lastTime = timeNow;
        }


        function tick() {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);
            drawScene();
            animate();
        }


        function webGLStart() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson05-canvas");
            initGL(canvas);
            initShaders();
            initBuffers();
            initTexture();

            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

            tick();
        }


        </script>



</head>

<body onload="webGLStart();">

            <canvas id="lesson05-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>


    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to turn on/off attributes and use a 1 pixel white texture. For example given a shader that users both textures and vertex colors like this

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_worldviewProjection * a_position;
  v_color = a_color;
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
varying vec4 v_color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * v_color;
}
```

Assume you look up locations like this

```
var colorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation("a_color");
var texcoordLoc = gl.getAttribLocatoin("a_texcoord");
```

Then, for models that use only textures turn off the color attribute and set it to white

```
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);
gl.vertexAttrib4f(colorLoc, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

For models that use only vertex colors turn off the texture coord attribute and use a 1x1 pixel white texture.

```
// at init time make a 1x1 white texture.
whiteTex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([1, 1, 1, 1]));


// at draw time...
// bind the white texture
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
// turn off texcoords.
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLoc);
```

This technique is often used in games because switching shader programs is slow.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to have both in one shader but the amount of coding (empty/redundant buffers) and performance issues (GPUs are very bad at branching) coming with it are not worth the effort, so effectively no. To have both in the same scene it's advised to use specialized shaders for each rendering procedure. You'll come across this in [Lesson 13](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1523).

About how much time it takes to get a grasp, well... it depends on what you eventually want to do with it. If you just want to make something more simple like a showroom for 3D models or some nifty effects for images and videos then you could save a lot of time by skipping the core and use [three.js](http://threejs.org/); but if you want to write your own engine then there's a lot more to do than just flipping around buffers to display stuff on the screen.

And while more powerful, javascript also requires more creative thinking, you may want to have a look at [Douglas Crockford about javascript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M) before continuing.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I think I may learn both- the general rudimentary nature of WebGL, I think, would be beneficial anyway- I am using it to model differential equations through waves - would three.js be better for that?

Comment: three.js is just a classic renderengine (like Ogre) ported to WebGL, it's main purpose is to ease creation and handling of objects, lights and camera in scenes and care for animations and effects etc. If you want to render mathematical stuff I'd say you're better off with raw webgl, and on that point you should check out [GLSL Sandbox](http://glsl.heroku.com/).